How to download file from Google Drive without GCP project using Python
I'm trying to automate a process to extract files periodically from Google Drive service. I'm confused because all the resources I've found so far are designed to be used with a GCP project. Are there any altertanives that doesn't require GCP?
This is the library that Google recommends to connect with its services https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python but I'm fairly new to API's and feeling a little overwhelmed.
I'd appreciate guidance on what to start looking, or any tip.

I think that in the case of the use of Drive API, it is required to retrieve the access token from OAuth2 or the service account created at  Google Cloud Platform if your files are not publicly shared. If your files are publicly shared, the file content can be obtained by this method without the access token and API key. But, if you want to retrieve the file metadata from the publicly shared file, at least, it is required to use the API key created at Google Cloud Platform. If my comment was not useful, I apologize.
